# Why did my question get migrated?

Tags: discussion, migration

I have a question about my Linguistics Stack Exchange post: [What are L, S, and F phonemes?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/47982/what-are-l-s-and-f-phonemes)

My question got moved to the Conlang stack exchange even though I already had an answer on the Linguistics one. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, questions should end up on the Stack that's best-equipped to answer them. Sometimes there's a lot of overlap between topics—it's not hard to see why conlangers would care about linguistics!—but procedural generation tools like that have more to do with conlangs than with linguistics in general.

If it's already gotten a good answer, that answer will remain after migrating, so nothing's actually getting lost.

(I'm not the one who migrated it, so this is just my best guess. But I do agree that migrating was the right choice.)